# Change typeof for specific keys for each object in json array

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript array, that contains JSON objects with 4 keys (team, pts, asts, rebs):

```
[
  {
     team: "A", 
     pts: "24",
     asts: "17",
     rebs: "14"
  },
  {
     team: "B", 
     pts: "24",
     asts: "11",
     rebs: "13"
  },     
  {
     team: "C", 
     pts: "14",
     asts: "27",
     rebs: "24"
  }
];
```

For some reason the **pts**, **asts**, and **rebs** data is all coming in as strings, whereas I need these to be numbers. Is there an easy way to specify an array of key names ["pts", "asts", "rebs"], and have the values for those key names convert from strings to numbers?

Been struggling with this for longer than I'd like to admit, any help is appreciated!

Comment: whoops meant to change the code to array, it's updated now.

Comment: `.forEach(e => { ["pts", "asts", "rebs"].forEach(prop => e[prop] = +e[prop]) });`, note that this does not include any error handling, but just shows an example of how to manipulate the properties.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON Object". Anyway, all those numbers are enclosed in quotes, which means they are strings unless you call `Number()` or `parseInt()` on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through the keys of object and convert them to numbers if they are of numeric value.

This can be accomplished by creating a simple function that does such a conversion and passing it to the `map` over the input data:

```
const input=[{team:"A",pts:"24",asts:"17",rebs:"14"},{team:"B",pts:"24",asts:"11",rebs:"13"},{team:"C",pts:"14",asts:"27",rebs:"24"}];

function convertStringKeysToNum(obj) {

    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((all, key) => {
        all[key] = Number(obj[key]) || obj[key];
        return all;
    },{})

}

const result = input.map(convertStringKeysToNum);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `reduce` to handle this:

```js
const arr = [
  {
     team: "A", 
     pts: "24",
     asts: "17",
     rebs: "14"
  },
  {
     team: "B", 
     pts: "24",
     asts: "11",
     rebs: "13"
  },     
  {
     team: "C", 
     pts: "14",
     asts: "27",
     rebs: "24"
  }
];

const result = arr.map(el => Object.keys(el).reduce((acc, curr) => ({
  ...acc,
  ...curr === 'team' ? {[curr]: el[curr]} : {[curr]: Number(el[curr])},
}), {}));

console.log(result);
```